# Url.Action and LinkGenerator returns different URLs

Tags: asp.net-core

On an Asp.Net Core 2.2 Controller action I have the following:

```
  var url1 = Url.Action(action: "GetContentByFileId", values: new { FileId = 1 });

  var url2 = _linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(HttpContext, action: "GetContentByFileId", values: new { FileId = 1 });
```

I get the right url in URL1 but URL2 is null ...

I am injecting LinkGenerator in the Controller and it is not null so I think it is ok ...

Any idea of what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the intended controller in the second call.

```
var url2 = _linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(HttpContext, 
    action: "GetContentByFileId",
    controller: "ControllerNameHere", //<--
    values: new { FileId = 1 }
);
```

The first call is already aware of the controller via the current `ActionContext` that was injected into the `UrlHelper`